# Density of invertible matrices: what properties on the base field?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

It is standard that the group of invertible matrices $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in the space of matrices $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. We can for instance see this by the finite number of roots for the characteristic polynomial, and approach the original matrix by avoiding them.

I wonder what properties on the base field are needed for this to hold. With the above proof, we would need an infinite field with a density property to approach zero, but then it should be dense since it is a (topological) field.

Does it mean that, for a given infinite field $K$, $GL_n(K)$ is dense in $M_n(\overline{K})$ where $\overline{K}$ is something where $K$ is dense? (is there a canonical notion of "closure"? maybe we need to suppose $K$ is already given with a close field containing it?)

Comment: If the topology is non-discrete then there is a sequence $x_n\in K^*,x_n\to 0$. For $A\in M_n(K)$, since $\det(A+tI)$ has finitely many roots then for $N$ large enough $A+x_n I\in GL_n(K)$ and $A+x_nI\to A$. Next, it is obvious that $M_n(K)$ is dense in $M_n(F)$ where $F$ is the completion of $K$ which is a field since in the definition of topological field we assume that the all the operations are continuous.